# Create JSON.stringify payload from Google Sheets Cells

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, shopify

I have a script that will post available stock adjust to Shopify but I don't know how to extend that and get the payload from cells in the sheet and ideally loop the payload so I can update more than one item at a time.

REF: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/inventory/inventorylevel#adjust-2021-01

I want to have cells in the sheet for "location_id", "inventory_item_id", "available_adjustment" and loop these so I could have below for example.

| "location_id" | "inventory_item_id" | "available_adjustment" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11594563 | 34516664746035 | 1 |
| 11595526 | 34516664746851 | -1 |
| 11215528 | 34516664567861 | 5 |
| 11595574 | 34516664745685 | 6 |

This is the current script that is working but I need to manually change the payload and run one at a time where I want to be able to adjust a lot more in one hit.

````
    var url = "https://**********.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/inventory_levels/adjust.json";
  var payloaddata = {
  "location_id": "11594563",
  "inventory_item_id": "34516664746035",
  "available_adjustment": "-1"
  };
    var payload = JSON.stringify(payloaddata);
    var username = "*********";
    var password = "*********";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        payload: payload,
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password) }
    });

    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    Logger.log(data); 
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your code is working then try this:
I also assume that you spreadsheet looks like your table with same headers and same order of columns

```
function shopifyPost() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
  const [hA, ...rows] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const url = "https://**********.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/inventory_levels/adjust.json";
  rows.forEach((r, i) => {
    let pld = {};
    pld[hA[0]] = r[0];
    pld[hA[1]] = r[1];
    pld[hA[2]] = r[2];
    let payload = JSON.stringify(pld);
    let username = "*********";
    let password = "*********";
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      payload: payload,
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password) }
    });

  });
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

The first line looked like this: (after stringifying it)

```
{"location_id":11594563,"inventory_item_id":34516664746035,"available_adjustment":1}
```

This is what my data sheet looked like:

| location_id | inventory_item_id | available_adjustment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11594563 | 34516664746035 | 1 |
| 11595526 | 34516664746851 | -1 |
| 11215528 | 34516664567861 | 5 |
| 11595574 | 34516664745685 | 6 |

Comment: Awesome solution, I can use the same code on other scenarios now too.